# Check if login is in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

My current code lets me through to the next page even if the username/password is false, which is obv not the wanted effect, where am I going wrong? what should be put in this if-statement?

```
private bool UserLogin(string un, string pw){
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select username from users where username=@un and password=@pw", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@un", un);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", pw);
        con.Open();
        string result = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync());
        if (????????????)
        {
            return true; 
        }
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: Don't store plain text passwords in the database. Use a hashing algorithm with a salt.

Comment: Also consider using a framework for handling logins. don't roll your own

Comment: I kno I kno, but this is strictly for learning how to crawl, then I can start walking and running

Comment: Any chance you might be able to tell us your website url? Or even better, the IP to your database? #justasking

Comment: its local, I wudnt create a website without hashed pws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the the Execution try replacing `cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync()` with :

```
cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

if you pretend to return a Synchronous execution by returning the a result inside the same function using "Async" methods may not work as intend.

Or try this but I guess it makes not much sense, at least to me:

```
object obj = await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();
```

**await** will do the trick.

Comment: Isn't ExecuteScalarAsync execution?

Comment: @shree.pat18 no it is returning a Task<T> which is the reference to when the code gets really executed.

Comment: ExecuteScalar(); solved my problem. Any idea why the login wont dissapear after user has been authenticated? Ive set VisibleWhenLoggedIn to false